# NSLocalizedString error

Tags: objective-c, ios, nslocalizedstring

I created 2 InfoPlist.strings, one in portuguese and the other in english.
i use my string in .strings file like this:

```
"BtnTitle" = "Title"; (English)
"BtnTitle" = "Título"; (Portuguese)
```

when i debug either in the simulator and in the device gives me only :
`BtnTitle` as the result of the NSLog :

```
NSLog(@"Titulo : %@", NSLocalizedString(@"BtnTitle", @""));
```

The Log dont give me the property of the object "Title" or "Título", but the object name "BtnTitle"

Comment: What is your current language setting?

Comment: Did u try changing your language on your device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`InfoPlist.strings` is localization for `Info.plist`. UI strings should go in `Localizable.strings`.